# Massive content importing into HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I still stuck and need your help my canvas project. I got the idea of a template, what I want to see there and I want to insert a content now there. From my last question about I have this working canvas template: jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/LmCwZ/2/ Here is the idea of what I want to have at my first tab. Hopefully with your help creating first main tab, I will carry on expanding example and working by myself. 
 First tab example: http://i.imgur.com/5Anzfny.png 
How I can do this for my first tab? Some of the text content should be automatically update by application.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Ken suggests in his answer to your last question, layout of complex content is usually done with HTML+CSS.   A nice tool to give you tabs is jqueryUI's tab control: https://jqueryui.com/tabs/  A production application would use HTML+CSS.

But since you're coding a project for learning purposes, here is how you can create "templates" for your tab content.

JavaScript has a variable called an `object`.  Objects are kind of like arrays because that one object can hold multiple pieces of information.  Each piece of information in an object is labeled.

An object that holds info about text you want to include in your template might look like this:

```
var myTextObject1 = { text:"Hello", x:100, y:20 };

var myTextObject2 = { text:"World", x:100, y:35 };
```

To make your template, create a contents array and save your objects in that array

```
var contents=[];

contents.push(myTextObject1);

contents.push(myTextObject2);
```

Then when you activate this tab you can use the objects to draw content on your tab

```
for(var i=0;i<contents.length;i++){
    drawTextContent( contents[i] );
}

function drawTextContent(text){
    ctx.fillText(text.text,text.x,text.y);
}
```

Of course you will need to create different kinds of objects:

- an object that defines text.
- an object that defines an image.
- an object that defines a background rectangle.
- an object that defines a captioned image (image+text).

Here's starting example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/WNaLn/

[image]

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    // get a reference to the canvas and context
    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    // the contents[] array will hold individual content objects
    // the content objects will be used to later draw the content to the tab
    var contents=[];

    // load a test image
    var house=new Image();
    house.onload=start;
    house.src="houseIcon.png";


    function start(){

        // create some test contents

        // tab background

        addBackgroundRect(0,0,275,275,"red");

        // left panel example

        addBackgroundRect(10,10,100,250,"lavender");

        addImageContent(house,50,15,20,20);

        addImageContent(house,75,65,20,20);

        addImageContent(house,50,110,20,20);

        addImageContent(house,15,65,20,20);

        addImageContent(house,40,65,30,30);

        // right panel example

        addBackgroundRect(110,10,150,100,"white");

        addTextContent("Text1",115,20,"red");
        addTextContent("Text2",115,40,"red");
        addTextContent("Text3",115,60,"red");
        addTextContent("Text4",115,80,"red");

        addTextImageContent("Caption",house,175,20,60,60);

        drawContents(contents);
    }

    // draw all content in the contents array

    function drawContents(contents){

        for(var i=0;i<contents.length;i++){
            var content=contents[i];
            //
            switch (content.type){
                case "background":
                    drawBackgroundRect(content);
                    break;
                case "text":
                    drawTextContent(content);
                    break;
                case "image":
                    drawImageContent(content);
                    break;
                case "textImage":
                    drawTextImageContent(content);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }


    // draw contents based on a content object

    function drawBackgroundRect(bk){
        ctx.fillStyle=bk.color;
        ctx.fillRect(bk.x,bk.y,bk.width,bk.height);
    }
    //
    function drawTextContent(text){
        ctx.fillStyle=text.color;
        ctx.fillText(text.text,text.x,text.y);
    }
    //
    function drawImageContent(img){
        ctx.drawImage(img.image,img.x,img.y,img.width,img.height);
    }
    //
    function drawTextImageContent(tImg){
        ctx.drawImage(tImg.image,tImg.x,tImg.y,tImg.width,tImg.height);
        ctx.fillStyle="black";
        ctx.fillRect(tImg.x,tImg.y+tImg.height-15,tImg.width,15);
        ctx.fillStyle="white";
        ctx.fillText(tImg.text,tImg.x+5,tImg.y+tImg.height-4);
    }


    // create content objects

    function addBackgroundRect(x,y,width,height,color){
        contents.push({
            type:"background",
            x:x,
            y:y,
            width:width,
            height:height,
            color:color
        });
    }
    //
    function addTextContent(text,x,y,color){
        contents.push({
            type:"text",
            text:text,
            x:x,
            y:y,
            color:color
        });
    }
    //
    function addImageContent(imgObject,x,y,width,height){
        contents.push({
            type:"image",
            image:imgObject,
            x:x,
            y:y,
            width:width,
            height:height
        });
    }
    //
    function addTextImageContent(text,imgObject,x,y,width,height){
        contents.push({
            type:"textImage",
            text:text,
            image:imgObject,
            x:x,
            y:y,
            width:width,
            height:height
        });
    }


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```